# Button to clipboard in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am looking to scrape `hashtags` generated from a site using Selenium webdriver. Since the site is using `Shadow Content (User Agent)` I decided to just copy the `hashtags` using the button already in the site that copies them into my clipboard. However, I am failing to locate the `<button>`

This is the HTML

`<button type="button" id="copyBtn" data-clipboard-target="#hashtag_textarea" class="btn btn-success">Copy to clipboard</button>`

How is it that Selenium can't find the button. What am I doing wrong.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/user/Documents/docs/chromedriver')
browser.get('https://seekmetrics.com/hashtag-generator')
delay = 15
print ("Headless Chrome Initialized")
print ("\n")

try:
    element = wait(browser, delay).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'el-input__inner')))
    element.click()
    element.send_keys('love')
    element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    wait(browser, delay)
    browser.find_element_by_id('copyBtn').click()
    print('Page is ready!')
    # print(hashtags.text)
    # print (browser.page_source)
except TimeoutException:
    print("Loading took too much time!")

browser.quit()
```

Comment: try to use  `browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()="Copy to clipboard"]")`

Comment: I get `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[text()='Copy to clipboard']"}`

Comment: This is the XPath `//*[@id="copyBtn"]` and yet I get the same error

Comment: I tried your code you just need some modifications take a look at my answer

Comment: worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to click the button just get textarea `value` but It need to wait until the `textarea` located.

```
element.send_keys('love')
element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
# wait until hashtags generated
hashtags = wait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'hashtag_textarea')))
print(hashtags.get_attribute('value'))
print('Page is ready!')
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I couldn't find it because of the `Shadow Content (User Agent)` line. Your code **really** helped me understand why.

Comment: you're welcome. It not Shadow Content or `#shadow-root` it just dynamically generated.

Comment: True, btw in `https://www.all-hashtag.com/hashtag-generator.php`, what would you use to `get_attribute` from a result?

Comment: From `<div id="copy-hashtags" class="copy-hashtags">` I tried `hashtag.get_attribute('copy-hashtsags')`

Comment: `get_attribute('textContent')` or `get_attribute('innerHTML')` or just `hashtag.text`

Answer (score 1):

after inputing value in textbox page refreshed and it takes some amount of time during that time your code tries to click on button which is not clickable or say not loaded in DOM. instead doing that wait for button until it becomes clickable check following code sample:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Python27\Scripts\chromedriver')
browser.get('https://seekmetrics.com/hashtag-generator')
delay = 15
print ("Headless Chrome Initialized")
print ("\n")

try:
    element = wait(browser, delay).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'el-input__inner')))
    element.click()
    element.send_keys('love')
    element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    wait(browser, delay)
    button = wait(browser, delay).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Copy to clipboard']")))
    button.click()
    print('Page is ready!')
    # print(hashtags.text)
    # print (browser.page_source)
except TimeoutException:
    print("Loading took too much time!")

browser.quit()
```

hope this helps you..